# JBoss - IBM IMS connector

Tags: jboss

Please guide me in configuring IMS Resource adapter for jboss(IBM IMS connector in JBoss). Followed the steps mentioned in the below link, but got stuck in defining connection definition.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html-single/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/index.html#Deploy_a_Resource_Adapter

Comment: Did you get any progress on this issue? I have similar requirement

Comment: Yes. I am able to do that. Please let me know what information is required from me

Comment: I have successfully configured IMS TM resource adapter. How to test whether it is able to talk to host or IMS using IMS connector?